# Encoding a Char in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, char

So I'm trying to simply encode a character into a file but for some reason it's not working. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) where I've found the example code and here is my code:

```
public class derp : MonoBehaviour{
    public Char[] chars = new Char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'r', 't', 'h'};

    void Start(){
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(chars);

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath+"/testing.wld", FileMode.Create);
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++){
            stream.WriteByte(encodedBytes[i]);
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

I ran the script, opened it and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngUEC.jpg) is what the file looks like:

I don't want any old person to be able to open the file and edit the data that's in it. However the picture clearly shows it's possible. My code isn't any different than the code in the example but for some reason the file doesn't have encoded data. So why isn't this working? Why isn't the data encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the data is encoded, but it sounds like you wanted it to be *encrypted*.  UTF-8 isn't for cryptography; it's just a character set.  UTF-8 encoding looks exactly like ASCII, which is why Notepad can read the file.

If you want to encrypt the file, one option is RSA encryption.  Check out the RSACryptoServiceProvider class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will be encoded - in UTF8...

Answer (score 0):

The data *is* being encoded, and everything is working as documented, and as expected by everyone who knows UTF8. Perhaps your own expectations don't match reality? What did you think "UTF8" was and what "encoding" meant?

Comment: I though when I encoded something it made the data unreadable, it made it so nobody can read the data and edit it around? I want a file unreadable and I though encoding was the solution to that? Your telling me the data is encoded but when I print it out to a file to be stored it's not. You can open the file and easily change what's in it because it's humanly readable. I though it would be some crazy non-human readable characters thus making the data not editable unless you use my program.

Comment: You're confusing "encoding" with "encryption."  What you want is encryption.  See my post, or check out http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_vs_encryption/

Comment: @MrSplosion: I'm afraid your expectations are by and large entirely wrong. You should consult some literature on the basics of information processing and text encoding, I suppose. The process of making data unreadable to eavesdroppers is called "encryption", and that's an entirely different field.